# OS X 10.8: reset approved, unsigned application memory

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

With OS X 10.8 Apple introduced a feature to make it harder to install unsigned applications. Usually, it works to right-click the unsigned application, choose `Open` and confirm the occurring dialog. The next time, this application can be launched like any signed one.

How can I reset OS X' knowledge of the confirmed application, so it will reject to launch it the next time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gate Keeper uses the *quarantine* functionality that has been present for a while to annoy users after they download files.

You can examine a file's quarantine information by reading its `com.apple.quarantine` *extended attribute*. Here I do this for a never before launched `.app` copied from a downloaded `.dmg`:

```
$ xattr -l Butler.app/
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;50697c0e;Safari;942183F8-A268-447B-AEAB-55CEA27DD911
```

The first value is the *quarantine state* (i.e. the interesting part). It's followed by a hex-encoded Unix timestamp (in this case: `date -r 0x50697c0e` results in `Mo  1 Okt 2012 13:18:38 CEST`), the name of the application creating the file, and a unique identifier (UUID) of the original quarantined item. This last one is inherited by extracted files from their container, in this case, the `.dmg` file.

---

The first part of the extended attribute is the quarantine state. When downloaded and never opened, this file has `0002`, [possibly indicating a web download](http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.de/2012/06/gatekeeper-xprotect-and-quarantine.html).

When you double-click the app, but abort when asked for confirmation, it's `0022` (probably to record earlier execution without approval), and when you confirm execution once, it's `0062`. In that case, you won't be asked again afterwards. This looks a lot like an octal or hexadecimal representation of a bit field, with the third `4` value bit indicating approval, and the third `2` value bit indicating prior execution.

By resetting this value to the original state after download, you can **re-enable the Gate Keeper protection**. Just read the value after opening (`xattr -p com.apple.quarantine <filename>`) and replace it with the same value, without the "this was already approved" bits (e.g. `xattr -w com.apple.quarantine 0002;[rest of the previous value] <filename>`).

Comment: Thanks for the details. Is this correct: if I build an (unsigned) application myself, it will not contain any quarantine information and hence not show up the nag dialog?

Comment: @MikeL. The quarantine information is added by the downloading program when creating the file. Download via `wget` and circumvent the issue. While I didn't test it, I doubt Xcode sets quarantine information.